# Connect multiple I2C to an Uno

Tags: i2c, arduino-pro-mini

Is it possible to use more than 1 device that needs to use SDA for I2C with a mini?
Would you use a different analogue pin with a 10k pull up resistor and tie all of the devices to the SCL?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to use more than 1 device that needs to use SDA for I2C with a mini?

Yes, provided they have unique I<sup>2</sup>C addresses.

> Would you use a different analogue pin with a 10k pull up resistor and tie all of the devices to the SCL?

No. All of the devices must be tied to both SDA and SCL. You may need a smaller resistor depending on how many devices there are; see NXP document UM10204 for details.